# Is it possible to apply FormData to an existing form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-data

If I have an existing form, I know I can effectively "convert" it to FormData by passing the form to the FormData constructor like in this example:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

var myFormData = new FormData(myForm);
//Now myFormData contains all fields from myForm
```

Is there any way to effectively do the inverse of this operation? I have an existing FormData object, and I want to apply its fields to a form in the DOM. Something like `myForm.setFormData()` (which I totally made up in) this example:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append(...); //etc...

var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.setFormData(myFormData);
//Now myForm contains all fields from myFormData
```

Is there any way to apply FormData to an existing form?

Comment: There isn't, The FormData object does not expose any of the fields it contains. All it has is the append method.

Comment: @Musa - So it's literally only useful in an ajax context? Is there any other way to even use FormData except via xhr?

Comment: As far as I can tell `FormData` is only used with `XMLHttpRequest.send`

Comment: there is a way in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406520/populate-an-html-form-from-a-formdata-object

Answer (score 5):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828870/is-it-possible-to-apply-formdata-to-an-existing-form#comment31237296_20828870) by [Musa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa) is in alignment with the MDN documentation [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

> The [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). It is primarily intended for use in sending form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to transmit keyed data.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)</sup>

Unfortunately, there appears to (currently) be no such method to apply fields from a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object onto a [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects</sub>