# Populate an HTML Form from a FormData object

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to store a FormData object of a form and then use that FormData object later to repopulate the stored FormData values back into the form?

For example:
**HTML**

```
<form id="test_form">
  <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/><br/>
  <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/><br/>
  <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Date of Birth"/><br/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var f = document.getElementById('test_form');
var data = FormData(f);
...
// mythical function to translate FormData back into form values
f.values(data);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `data`?

Comment: I want to use it to populate an HTML form's field values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033425/1869660) and [this](http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml), here is how I serialize and deserialize form data:

```
function formSerialize(form) {
    const data = new FormData(form);
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033425/1869660
    return new URLSearchParams(data).toString();
}

function formDeserialize(form, data) {
    const entries = (new URLSearchParams(data)).entries();
    for(const [key, val] of entries) {
        //http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml
        const input = form.elements[key];
        switch(input.type) {
            case 'checkbox': input.checked = !!val; break;
            default:         input.value = val;     break;
        }
    }
}
```

*Warning: `formDeserialize()` won't clear fields that are not included in the stored data, e.g. empty radio groups or checkboxes. Also, not tested with all `<input>` types.*

Comment: Thank you, this is the best and closest thing I have seen to a solution. Would prefer a native function, but I will test this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful  I've stumbled upon a problem with file fields which you can't populate so I'm skipping them like this `if (!input || input.type === "file") continue;` right after `const input = ..` before the switch, could also be done as part of the switch of course.

Comment: Also I switched the part getting the input to `form.elements.namedItem(key)`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the answer to your question, but if you have JQuery and JQuery View engine, you can use this:

```
var f = document.getElementById('test_form');
var data = FormData(f);

// Fill the form using JQuery view Engine:
$("#test_form").view(f);
```

See example on: https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/docs/form

Comment: This isn't the exact answer, but incredibly informative and useful idea! I will definitely be looking at this project for other applications. It's basically a super lightweight front-end framework.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with creating the FormData object from the test_form ID.

You can access all the values from the FormData object as so:

```
var f = document.getElementById('test_form');
var data = new FormData(f);

var lastName = data.get('last_name');
var firstName = data.get('first_name');
var dob = data.get('date_of_birth');
```

You can also use FormData.getAll to pull all of the data from the object.

```
var allData = data.getAll;
```

Hopefully this is what you were asking, if not please let me know and we can get it figured out.

Comment: I know I can access the properties individually with `.get`, but, on a form with dozens of fields, it would be helpful to be able to populate those form fields from a form data object without needing to do it one field at a time or knowing the names of the fields in advance. The `.getAll` function is in the right direction, but looking for a way to put those values back into the correct form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can store value to variables using FormData but cannot populate back using values. You need to populate for every field individually using script.

Answer (score -5):

You can use localStorage or sessionStorage objects.

Like

```
localStorage.data = data; //untill clear the browsing history
```

or

```
sessionStorage.data = data; //untill session complete
```